# How can I decorate my github profile adding some graphs analytics, skill badges etc

Tags: github

I saw people add many graphs, analytics, badges and many more things in their github profile. But how do they do this? See the attached picture and tell me about the process please.[someone's github profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS1mJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to be new here to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is a site where programmers help one another solve problems or issues that they are having with their code, environment, etc. Generally a question such as this would be closed, well at least from my experience. When asking a question you should probably ask something related to code or an issue (never ask how to do something with no existing code because people don't like that, coming from experience). Really only ask a question if there's an issue and a solution.

Back to your question, you can get all that stuff in that screenshot under stats [here](https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats) and you can add the tech stack stuff with any old github readme badge like [this](https://github.com/alexandresanlim/Badges4-README.md-Profile) one. Just add what they tell you to your profiles markdown file, if you don't know how to do that look [here](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme).